# Creating an stable ERC20 coin for Commerce

Tags: erc-20, ether, stablecoins

I am looking to build a euro backed stable coin that is built on ETH.

We have liquidity behind it to keep it pegged. This would be used on a ecommerce site to buy physical items and than users will be rewarded with the token and incentivized to use the token thru loyalty rewards.

What fiat to crypto on/off ramp would work best in this situation? We ideally want to keep this in house. And what would be the best processor to use the token to buy the items.